# Why can't I load database values onto my listview?

Tags: c#, mysql, listview

I have this code:

```
listView10.Items.Clear();
MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("Server=166.62.27.186;Database=xxxx;Uid=xxxx;Pwd=xxxx;");

MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select * from appoint order by times asc", con);
MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
con.Open();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    ListViewItem Item = new ListViewItem(dr["Customer"].ToString());
    Item.SubItems.Add(dr["Kind"].ToString());
    Item.SubItems.Add(dr["connum"].ToString() + "/" + dr["telnum"].ToString());
    Item.SubItems.Add(dr["times"].ToString());
    Item.SubItems.Add(dr["address"].ToString());
    Item.SubItems.Add(dr["type"].ToString());
    Item.SubItems.Add(dr["notes"].ToString());
    listView10.Items.Add(Item);
}
con.Close()
```

it should load the value in the table but it doesn't.
When I connected the database to the Mysql Workbench it seems the connection is working. in my winform application it can insert into the database yet it still doesnt load. i as i observed I noticed that after executing :

```
da.Fill(dt);
```

It just stops there and doesn't execute the foreach statement. What seems to be the problem i don't understand. 
I will provide more information if needed, im kinda in a rush tomorrow is our defense in our thesis. thanks in advance

pics when debugging

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Since `foreach` loop doesn't do anything, it's possible that `dt.Rows` has no rows (empty results). Have you checked that?

Comment: Did you debug this? Look what´s in `dtRows`.

Comment: how can i debug dt.rows? in the breakpoint it shows {} which definitely means its null right?

Comment: Just set your breakpoint at the line of your `foreach`-statement and see what´s in the variable. `{ }` doesn´t mean `null`, but empty. So your table doesn´t have any rows.

Comment: updated my post. thats what it shows while debugging

Comment: @yuzirui `{}` indicates empty rows instead of null value. Check if your query working properly, or try `DataTable.Load()` with `MySqlDataReader`.

Comment: though it seems that it doesnt execute foreach. it doesnt stop there

Comment: As allready mentioned your query doesn´t return any rows, that´s why the loop won´t iterate anything. Did you look at the table if it contains any row at all? Did you test your query directly on the db? However the code *after* the loop surely will execute.

Comment: ill try changing query

Comment: You stated "connection is working", but I want to know if "the query is working" in MySQL environment. Has `appoint` table contains any data?

Comment: yes it contains data, ill edit my post again and show a picture of it

Comment: Read debugging basics first.

Comment: in workbench,the query is also working and returns all data according to the date

Comment: tetsuya was right, i used dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader()); and it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`DataTable.Load()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.load(v=vs.110).aspx) method with `MySqlDataReader.ExecuteReader()` method as alternative to `MySqlDataAdapter` to retrieve data like this example:

```
using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("Server=166.62.27.186;Database=xxxx;Uid=xxxx;Pwd=xxxx;"))
{
    con.Open();
    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select * from appoint order by times asc", con))
    {
        MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(rdr);
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            ListViewItem Item = new ListViewItem(dr["Customer"].ToString());
            Item.SubItems.Add(dr["Kind"].ToString());
            Item.SubItems.Add(dr["connum"].ToString() + "/" + dr["telnum"].ToString());
            Item.SubItems.Add(dr["times"].ToString());
            Item.SubItems.Add(dr["address"].ToString());
            Item.SubItems.Add(dr["type"].ToString());
            Item.SubItems.Add(dr["notes"].ToString());
            listView10.Items.Add(Item);
        }
    }
    con.Close();
}
```